# Automate the product creation and the related node

Tags: commerce

- I've a View that shows me some data from an external system (Moodle Views).
- I want to add the functionality to create a new product (using the Commerce module) with
  the main fields automatically filled and then create the related node to show the product 
  also filled.
- The user should view only the filled form for the new node, not the intermediate passage 
  of creating the product.

What is the best way to do it (both via code or using some module)? 
I just need a starting point.